# How to switch a 200 Vpp AC signal @ 2000 Hz in under 1 millisecond?

Tags: ac, switching, solid-state-relay, high-frequency, igbt

I want to switch a ~120 V AC signal with a frequency of up to 2000 Hz.
For my application (driving electrolumnescent wire) it is important that the switching duration is not higher than about one millisecond.
I also want to drive this from an ESP32, with a logic level signal of 3.3V DC.
The AC is being created by an DC-to-AC-inverter running at 5 V or 12 V, depending on the expected load.

What part or circuit would be able to accomplish this? I need it to be very small, i.e. a microchip, rather than some kind of module. I want 8 channels of this on a credit card sized PCB if possible.

I have been reading about IGBTs and SSRs supposedly being able to handle this, but I ahve trouble finding appropriate parts.

Comment: Is the input a sine wave or square wave? You may need to draw a diagram to explain this.

Comment: Please link the DC-to-AC converter's data sheet. When you say "switch" are you wanting to isolate the AC signal from the load or just maybe "modulate" the AC signal? What is the load? How long between switching? Please draw a picture.

Comment: Here is an example of such a wave form: https://learn.adafruit.com/el-wire/using-el-wire
The time between switching is about 16ms which is the sampling window of the microphone. The project is about real time music visualisation.

Comment: @Mattman944 I have been using this part before but it broke. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10878
I assume the TRAICs cannot handle the high frequency of the AC as they are designed for 50/60 Hz.

Comment: Are you saying you want to *switch* at 2 kHz (i.e. 4000 switch operations per second) or that the AC that you want to switch has a frequency of 2 kHz? If the former, you need a lot faster than just "under 1 ms".

Comment: Bck to back (series opposed) MOSFET should be suitable.\

Comment: @Heart I want to switch an AC signal of 200 Vpp @ 2000 Hz. The switching delay should be under one millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

200 Vpp and "microchip sized" is not going to work – for isolation properties alone (but maybe my idea of a microchip is just very small).

Other than that, switching currents isn't really hard, especially when they're AC, because transistors large enough to block that voltage do exist, and so do thyristors and triacs – and these are exactly the thing that's in your halogen lamp dimmer (hint: circuits from there). 1 ms is quite long, in semiconductor terms.

The problem is more that AC flows through capacitors – and a blocking semiconductor junction (such in an "off" transistor or thyristor, or just a diode in reverse) acts exactly as that. So, depending on how much current you consider to be "no significant current", this might require overdimensioning your switching device, or putting multiple in series.

Regarding the 3.3V: you'll typically need some higher voltage to turn on a thyristor (triac), so you'd need to generate a DC voltage roughly at your peak voltage (but that's easy – half-wave rectifier and a capacitor!), and have a high-side switch on that, which you in term control from your microcontroller using a MOSFET.

Now, regarding speed: EL wire is capacitive in nature, so I don't think it will turn off in 1 ms if it has any significant length, and that's not even due to the charge carrier life time in the light-emitting dielectric.

Regarding the design: Why not simply build a step-up converter / inverter that has a "enable/disable" pin? That would seem the intuitive way.

Comment: I have read that there exists no TRAICs that can switch 2 kHz reliably/without breaking. I have made that experience and I think the "Sparkfun EL Sequencer" has been discontinued for exactly that reason. I currently have a circuit of 8 of the smallest inverters that I could find. But that circuit seems visually sluggisch compared to directly switching the AC and it is also rather heavy and big like a battery pack.

Comment: 200V SSR with sub ms rise/falls times should exist in a standard SOP-4 package (~4x4 mm2), eg. TLP172GM @ThomasHirsch. Only 100mA though. To address capacitive off-leakage, one could add another switch to ground the off-side..16 such switches easily fit in a credit card and work off of 3.3V.

Comment: @tobalt The current is not really a problem. EL-wire (with 2.3mm diameter) draws 10 to 15mA per meter and I don't plan on connecting more than 3 meter per channel so 100mA exactly fits the bill.

Comment: @tobalt What would be the switching delay of this component it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: @ThomasHirsch definitely in there, section 13 "switching characteristics"; the worst-case time doesn't matter really to you, because your voltage makes a zero-crossing twice in that time, which will definitely help turn off the transistors quicker.

Comment: @ThomasHirsch check tr/tf (rise and fall time) ratings. it's about a (few) 100 us. Also check similar parts from other manufacturers..They are all pin compatible and have similar ratings but might differ spec-wise here and there.

Comment: @tobalt I could not find any information about the frequency of AC this part would be able to switch. How would I be sure that it can handle 2 kHz?

Comment: @ThomasHirsch It can switch DC, so AC is no problem. Check how much off-leakage to expect through its small capacitance though. See my earlier comment above